# adding anova test result in box plot by ggpubr in r

Tags: r, boxplot, ggpubr

I have my data below and I would like to plot a multiple box plot with the ANOVA test result shown on the plot.

```
> combined
   SampleID     chao1 Samples Sgroup Bgroup Duration
1     BSS21 1275.1071   BSS20    BSS      S      20d
2     BSS22 1575.4972   BSS20    BSS      S      20d
3     BSS23 1381.2963   BSS20    BSS      S      20d
4     BSS41 1090.0254   BSS40    BSS      S      40d
5     BSS42 1103.6522   BSS40    BSS      S      40d
6     BSS43 1065.7177   BSS40    BSS      S      40d
7     BSS61 1077.8776   BSS60    BSS      S      60d
8     BSS62 1123.5759   BSS60    BSS      S      60d
9     BSS63 1201.3571   BSS60    BSS      S      60d
10    BSW21  937.0231   BSW20    BSW      W      20d
11    BSW22  970.0462   BSW20    BSW      W      20d
12    BSW23 1070.1560   BSW20    BSW      W      20d
13    BSW41 1894.8606   BSW40    BSW      W      40d
14    BSW42 1825.0271   BSW40    BSW      W      40d
15    BSW43 1869.3494   BSW40    BSW      W      40d
16    BSW61 1332.4078   BSW60    BSW      W      60d
17    BSW62 1354.4593   BSW60    BSW      W      60d
18    BSW63 1365.2961   BSW60    BSW      W      60d
19     BW21 1533.9137    BW20     BW      W      20d
20     BW22 1643.1564    BW20     BW      W      20d
21     BW23 1572.8900    BW20     BW      W      20d
22     BW41 1678.0270    BW40     BW      W      40d
23     BW42 1596.9105    BW40     BW      W      40d
24     BW43 1684.8433    BW40     BW      W      40d
25     BW61 1060.2059    BW60     BW      W      60d
26     BW62 1127.0738    BW60     BW      W      60d
27     BW63 1097.7083    BW60     BW      W      60d
28     SS21 1751.0145    SS20     SS      S      20d
29     SS22 1662.5932    SS20     SS      S      20d
30     SS23 1806.3628    SS20     SS      S      20d
31     SS41 1302.9245    SS40     SS      S      40d
32     SS42 1126.5082    SS40     SS      S      40d
33     SS43 1122.6136    SS40     SS      S      40d
34     SS61 1429.4972    SS60     SS      S      60d
35     SS62 1402.5714    SS60     SS      S      60d
36     SS63 1493.1477    SS60     SS      S      60d
37     SW21 1559.5000    SW20     SW      W      20d
38     SW22 1387.1173    SW20     SW      W      20d
39     SW23 1563.9524    SW20     SW      W      20d
40     SW41 1439.0355    SW40     SW      W      40d
41     SW42 1508.0054    SW40     SW      W      40d
42     SW43 1425.1602    SW40     SW      W      40d
43     SW61 1488.0000    SW60     SW      W      60d
44     SW62 1398.9880    SW60     SW      W      60d
45     SW63 1497.8553    SW60     SW      W      60d
46     W011 1377.8092    W010    WCW      W      10d
47     W012 1304.3725    W010    WCW      W      10d
48     W013 1413.2292    W010    WCW      W      10d
49     W021 1377.8092    W010     BW      W      10d
50     W022 1304.3725    W010     BW      W      10d
51     W023 1413.2292    W010     BW      W      10d
52     W031 1377.8092    W010     SW      W      10d
53     W032 1304.3725    W010     SW      W      10d
54     W033 1413.2292    W010     SW      W      10d
55     W041 1377.8092    W010    BSW      W      10d
56     W042 1304.3725    W010    BSW      W      10d
57     W043 1413.2292    W010    BSW      W      10d
58     W051 1377.8092    W010     SS      W      10d
59     W052 1304.3725    W010     SS      W      10d
60     W053 1413.2292    W010     SS      W      10d
61     W061 1377.8092    W010    BSS      W      10d
62     W062 1304.3725    W010    BSS      W      10d
63     W063 1413.2292    W010    BSS      W      10d
64    WCW21 1246.5794   WCW20    WCW      W      20d
65    WCW22 1249.2180   WCW20    WCW      W      20d
66    WCW23 1134.3462   WCW20    WCW      W      20d
67    WCW41 1074.9192   WCW40    WCW      W      40d
68    WCW42  887.7191   WCW40    WCW      W      40d
69    WCW43  990.3733   WCW40    WCW      W      40d
70    WCW61  864.2727   WCW60    WCW      W      60d
71    WCW62  934.5111   WCW60    WCW      W      60d
72    WCW63  801.5696   WCW60    WCW      W      60d
```

I tried the `ggpubr` package in r and apply the `compare_means` function.
For the anova test, I got:

```
> compare_means(chao1~Duration,data=combined,method="anova",group.by = "Sgroup")

# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Sgroup .y.             p      p.adj p.format p.signif method
  <fct>  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
1 BSS    chao1 0.00394     0.0079     0.00394  **       Anova 
2 BSW    chao1 0.000000164 0.00000098 1.6e-07  ****     Anova 
3 BW     chao1 0.00000283  0.000014   2.8e-06  ****     Anova 
4 SS     chao1 0.0000996   0.0004     1.0e-04  ****     Anova 
5 SW     chao1 0.160       0.16       0.16005  ns       Anova 
6 WCW    chao1 0.000118    0.0004     0.00012  ***      Anova
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. Then I make the plot:

```
ggboxplot(combined,x="Samples", y="chao1",palette = "jco", add = "jitter",short.panel.labs = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~Sgroup,scales = "free")
```

and got:

[image]

I have tried so hard by the `stat_compare_means` function but I still cannot add my anova test result on the plot

Any suggestion will be helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems with `facet_wrap` in the past, it maybe that its not supported. Hopefully I'm proven wrong! If you want an alternative, you can use the `cowplot` package to build the grids yourself. It's more work, but allows more flexibility perhaps. Here is an example with the data used when you run `?stat_compare_means`

```
# packages
library(cowplot)
library(ggpubr)

# data from ggpubr
data("ToothGrowth")
head(ToothGrowth)

# define groups, build plots in a list and subset
groups <- unique(ToothGrowth$supp)

pl <- lapply(groups, function(g){
  p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp==g,], x = "dose", y = "len",
                 color = "dose", palette = "npg") + 
    stat_compare_means()
})

# use cowplot to bring together
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = pl, ncol = 2)
```